# How to reload .XCompose without a reboot?

Tags: compose-key

When I edit my `~/.XCompose` file, I need to reboot Ubuntu 16.04 for the changes to take effect.  Is there a way to tell Ubuntu to reload the definitions in the file without doing a full reboot?

Comment: Are you sure you need a reboot? Just close the application in which you intend using the Compose key and restart the application. Any modification to `~/.XCompose` should be effective immediately.

Comment: For some reason, restarting the application doesn't work for me.  In my system, changes are only recognized in all applications after a reboot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Restart the input method program you are running.  For a brute force approach, if your OS comes with `pidof`, you can use the following command:

```
pidof <INPUTMETHOD> | xargs kill -9; <INPUTMETHOD>
```

(Just replace  with the actual command for your input method program.)

Your input method may include a command to restart it.  In my case, it's `fcitx`, which offers this command:

```
fcitx -r
```

All changes are instantly activated. However, some applications may need to be restarted.

As ARX mentions in comments, `ibus` has its own command to restart as well:

```
ibus restart
```

Comment: This works for ibus.  You can also use "ibus restart" as a simpler alternative.  Thanks!

Comment: `ibus restart` works on Ubuntu 23.04, Unity, X11.

Comment: `ibus restart` also works in Ubuntu 23.04, Wayland.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on ubuntu 22.10, and my problem is that: I'm including files from ~/.XCompose, and if the modifications are inside the included files but not directly to ~/.XCompose, then apps won't pick up the updates. So I have to do a dummy editing directly inside ~/.XCompose, and restart apps.

To sum up:

1. Check that your updates is **directly** inside ~/.XCompose (not one of your included files). Or you need to do a dummy editing like me (retouching ~/.XCompose might also work).
2. Restart application.

If above not work, you might as well try these:

- restart input engine.
- restart X.
- relogin.